# How to disable Toolbar fade-in animation?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

Is there a way to disable the `fade-in / fade-out` animation for `ToolBar` elements?
I found a solution for the status bar:

```
getWindow().getEnterTransition().excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
```

But I can not find a similar fix for the `ToolBar`. Everytime I load a new Activity, it causes an undesired flash.

Edit:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Status Bar Color -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="21">@color/primary_4</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Toolbar Style -->
    <style name="toolbar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_0</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_0</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_3</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In **activity_main.xml** & **activity_details.xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:theme="@style/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary_4" />
```

Comment: Does your `toolbar` have `android:transitionName` attribute?

Comment: No it doesnt @bjiang

Comment: Any word about `transition` related to your toolbar?

Comment: Not at all, nothing in my styles.xml file, and it's defined outside of my shared view on both activities. It just seems to have the default fade transition.

Comment: Could the android:windowActivityTransitions item defined under my app theme (parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar") be related to my toolbar?

Comment: Yeah, kind of, you can try to remove that

Comment: So I just removed all the android:windowActivity / content Transitions defined in my styles.xml. All I have is my ActivityOptionsCompat and startActivity which passes one view as shared (Doesnt include the toolbar).. What gives?

Comment: post your toolbar layout.

Comment: Can you just give your `ToolBar` an ID and then exclude that target ID like you are doing with the status bar background?

Comment: Tried that and the same for android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, for some reason had no effect. @AlexLockwood

Answer (score 1):

The Elevation animation duration value is  [`R.integer.app_bar_elevation_anim_duration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.integer.html#app_bar_elevation_anim_duration) which by default is `150`.

To avoid the animation, just put following into any xml under res/values and that's it:

`<integer name="app_bar_elevation_anim_duration" tools:override="true">0</integer>`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for excludeTarget() says:

> public Transition excludeTarget (View target,
> boolean exclude) :
>
> Whether to add the given target to the list of targets to exclude from
> this transition. The exclude parameter specifies whether the target
> should be added to or removed from the excluded list.
>
> Excluding targets is a general mechanism for allowing transitions to
> run on a view hierarchy while skipping target views that should not be
> part of the transition. For example, you may want to avoid animating
> children of a specific ListView or Spinner. Views can be excluded
> either by their id, or by their instance reference, or by the Class of
> that view

This means that the way you excluded the status bar from the enter transition would also work for the toolbar.
I tried it and it's working.

secondActivity.xml:

```
...
<include
            android:id="@+id/customToolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
...
```

SecondActivity.java (Inside onCreate()):

```
...
getWindow().getEnterTransition().excludeTarget(R.id.customToolbar, true);
...
```